# NSPredicate expression to filter on count of a to-many relationship

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have a Core Data model with a one-to-many relationship e.g.:

```
@interface Person : NSManagedObect
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *children;
@end
```

I want to create a predicate which only gives me the `Person`s that have at least one child:

I tried:
`[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"person.children.count > 0"]`

But I get `NSPredicate to-many key not allowed`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Ok, I found some [documentation](https://realm.io/news/nspredicate-cheatsheet/) on the [realm.io](http://realm.io/) site about `NSPredicate` collection queries which has the answer:

You have to use `@count` instead of just `count`:

So: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"person.children.@count > 0"]`

Pity that Apple doesn't document this themselves (at least not that I could find).

Comment: That's because this is mainly a Key-Value Coding feature more than NSPredicate's: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE